# Clicking through a div

Tags: css, html

I'm making a website for my sister and I'm having a problem, the thing is I have a navigation bar from dynamic drive but I only put 2 links in it to test it.

I put it in a div with the css of:

```
position:absolute;  
margin-top:-30px;  
z-index:-1;  
overflow:hide;  
margin-left:1%;
```

I put it in a div so that the extra piece of the nav bar is hidden, but (problem) with that div I cant click on the links.

[DEMO](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55689678/Website/index.html)

Comment: Paste some code for these divs. Did you placed the links (a's) inside the divs?

Comment: @Rolice Im not too sure what you mean, ime a biginner the code is<div id="navbarcontaner">
<div id="navbar" class="ddsmoothmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="pics.html">Pictures</a></li>
<li><a target="navigator" href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
</ul>
<br style="clear: left" />
</div>
</div>

Comment: Paste your page code next time. Also, I suggest using jsfiddle to experiment with web page code (html/css/javascript).

Comment: There is a demo page to see the code. And using firebug it is easy to play around to get it to work.

Comment: @Marcin I tried it at jsfiddle, but Alot of prblem's appeared that wasn't there in the normal browser

Comment: @Stephan: It can help you by allowing you test, and demo, only the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @SamWarren: You don't think newbies should be told about tools?

Comment: Course they should. I was answering @rolice that the code was in the demo and the code didn't need copy-pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `z-index:-1` from your `#navbarcontaner` & give `position:relative` to your `#head`. Write like this:

```
#head {
    background-color: #BF60A0;
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 98%;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}
#navbarcontaner {
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: -30px;
    position: absolute;
}
#site h3{
 margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When i change the z-index to be 10 on the #navbarcontaner the links are clickable. Basically there is a div in front of the links and that is why they arent clickable.

Id recommend moving the #navbarcontaner down. Say padding-top:20px; and change the z-index to 10.

Comment: Those didn't work for me, for some reason, I guess It's becuz I'm using Opera Next?

Comment: whoops, saved it offline and tried to view it online - gunna try it again

Comment: sorry, but when I do that it seems to cause the problem that I fixed with putting the div there - basicly It's asif the div wasn't there and the rest of the empty line is showing again.

Answer (score 0):

Change your #framecontaner to this:

```
#framecontaner {
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 32px;
}
```

Or...

Change the `z-index` value from `-1` to `1` for you `#navbarcontaner`

Comment: whoops, saved it offline and tried to view it online - gunna try it again

Comment: Sorry for delay- internet problems, and yes it did seem to work.